# Use of "usted" to convey formality *and* affection? (in Ecuador)

Tags: dialectos, formalidad, parentesco, ustedeo, ecuador

My *prometida* (she's Ecuadorian) has occasionally referred to me as *usted*, but she said that in this context it can convey not only formality / respect, but also affection!  I'm fascinated by this concept, but curious if this is common in other Spanish-speaking regions.

I have read that in Colombia, *usted* is used nearly always (including towards children and pets), and seeing how Ecuador is a neighboring country, could this be dialectal assimilation of sorts?  (Side question:  Is it still the case in Colombia that the formal *usted* is used predominantly / more so than in other Latin American countries?)

Comment: Fascinating! In Japanese they have a similar case with the word _anata_. It is used in a way similar to _usted_, but it is also used by wives to refer lovingly to their husbands.

Comment: I remember reading a book (maybe by Gabo?) where an old couple that had been married for many years referred to each other using usted.  I thought it strange at the time (not being a native speaker) though this could very well explain it.  I will be interested to hear the answers to this question.

Comment: In Chile we do not use the word "usted" in these cases, but we can conjugate using the formal pattern when we talk with someone very dear, for example the mother with the son or the boyfriends with each other. E.g. "amorcito, a qué hora _va_ a llegar" (using formal "va" (usted) instead of informal "vas" (tú)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the use of "usted" to indicate affection is quite frequent in several countries in Latin America. At a footnote on page 8 of this [paper](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/coloquio_paris/ponencias/pdf/cvc_deniz.pdf), I have found this statement belonging to an author mentioned in the text:

> *<sup>12</sup> Este mismo autor señala cuáles son las situaciones en las que se observa con mayor frecuencia el uso de tú y, asimismo, indica que **la forma usted posee también en algunos países americanos un uso afectivo**, al que también aluden Alcina y Blecua (Gramática española, Ariel, Barcelona, 1991, 592), **cuando a los interlocutores los unen vínculos estrechos.***
>
> - [*El uso de las fórmulas de tratamiento en la actualidad: las formas* tú *y* usted *en el español de Canarias*](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/coloquio_paris/ponencias/pdf/cvc_deniz.pdf), Margarita Déniz Hernández

Answer (score 5):

I do not know much about Ecuadorian way of speaking but since you asked about Colombia let me say this.

We mainly use two forms: *Usted* and *Vos*. (there are many questions on this site about tuteo and voseo that you could check out.)

The *Usted* is the more commonly used on the south and central region while *vos* is more used around the "coffee region". However on the Caribbean part of the country the use of "tú" is very common.

The use of *tú* and *vos* in Colombia always means familiarity and is used among people that are close friends or with family while *usted* is always used with people that deserve some respect or people you do not know very well.

Regarding love relationships it is common for people to keep using the *usted* but most people cross the respect barrier and start using *tú* (or *vos* according to the region).

For us the *usted* alone does not mean affection. It could be used in a sentence that expresses affection but it is the meaning of the sentence and not the use of *usted* that conveys the feeling.

Being that your girlfriend is from Ecuador and that could mean that their ways are similar to our people from the south, I think it is very normal that she uses "usted".

Comment: Thank you for this answer -- I kinda remember 20 years ago when a co-worker (L1 Spanish speaker originally from Dominican Rep.) remarked at how _unusually_ formal Colombians spoke, especially addressing family and friends.  P.S. It seems that Coastal Colombia's language and grammar would be influenced by e.g. Panamá, Cuba, Puerto Rico, Dom. Rep., etc....

Comment: That is correct. Caribbean culture is similar to that from those countries you mention (not costal since language form the Pacific cost is very different) and they are more informal but in the south and most of the Andean region the use of _usted_ is the most common. I understand why this should sound very formal to other people but we don't see it quite that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have a close friend from Ecuador, who *always* uses *usted* with me.  My friend explained that their upbringing inculcated the custom of using *usted* with almost 100% of everyone they dealt with.  I guess the exception would be when talking to a small child who is a relative or a close friend -- but I even have a hard time imagining my friend using *tú* in that situation.

This related answer adds to what @DGaleano was explaining: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22491/9385