# The use of ustedes instead of vosotros when in Spain

Tags: pronombres

I have close Spanish friends who use "vosotros" when addressing me and my husband. As I speak Mexican Spanish, I never learned this form of "you-all" and use "ustedes" instead. Is this impolite? Do my Spanish friends think I am trying to keep a distance between us? And is it wrong for me to address children as "ustedes"? Must I go back to school and learn the vosotros conjugations?

Comment: @walen no me parece un duplicado ya que esta pregunta es sobre *ustedes* en plural y en la otra solo se habla del singular.

Comment: even thought they are not asking the same question, the answer from the other one answers this one as well, about how to use usted vs vos in spain

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. // Judy, I think this answer will help you: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22491/9385

Comment: @walen I don't think it's a duplicate. This question specifically refers to the perception of the other forms and need to change

Answer (score 1):

As you may already know, 'vosotros' is the informal treatment for the 2nd person in plural.

It is not impolite (doing the opposite, using vosotros in a formal scenario, might be).

I don't think you **must** go back to school and learn vosotros, and it would be just fine to learn it as you go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The issue of second person pronoun usage is something that often comes up with speakers across the Spanish speaking world.  Even in countries where the only three are *tú/Vd/Vds*, the customs of using each one will be different, and adding in *vos*, *sumercé* and *vosotros* just adds more options: the underlying "problem" is the same.

The reality is, however, that most Spanish speakers are somewhat accostumbed to this.  If I hear a Costa Rican call me *usted*, I don't necessarily assume much by it, just as when they hear me call them *tú* they tend to understand by my very different accent that I'm not used to the same formality distinctions as they are.  As a foreigner, you will be given even more latitude.  There are many other elements of speech — word choice, single pronoun usage, etc— that can help a Spanish speaker understand whether you are intending to be offensive/polite/friendly/etc.

Specifically in your example, if you regularly use *tú* with your friends individually, but then use *ustedes* for both, there will be no confusion: it's clear that you're using an *ustedes*-only dialect, and by virtue of using *tú* that you intend to be friendly/familiar with them.

You won't be expected to modify your dialect, and that's common across the Spanish-speaking world, although if you live for an extended period of time somewhere with a different system it might not be a bad idea to try to pick it up.